# Calculate UDP Checksum in Rust?

Tags: rust, udp, checksum

I am trying to manually build packets and am having trouble calculating a correct UDP checksum.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong in the below code? The packet being passed in is the complete packet to be sent with a placeholder for the UDP Checksum currently of 0x0000, but I sum the psuedoheader, udp header, and udp payload, but according to wireshark my UDP checksums are incorrect. (Mine: 0x9f4c vs Wireshark: 0x2b7b for example)

````
fn udp_checksum (packet: &Vec<u8>) -> [u8; 2] {
    let mut idx = 0;
    let mut idx_end = 2;
    let mut payload = &packet[42..];
    let payload_len = payload.len();
    if payload_len % 2 != 0 {
        payload.to_vec().push(0);
    }
    let source_ip_1 = BigEndian::read_u16(&packet[26..28]); //source ip 1 of 2
    let source_ip_2 = BigEndian::read_u16(&packet[28..30]); //source ip 2 of 2
    let dest_ip_1 = BigEndian::read_u16(&packet[30..32]); //dest ip 1 of 2
    let dest_ip_2 = BigEndian::read_u16(&packet[32..34]); //dest ip 2 of 2
    let udp_len = BigEndian::read_u16(&packet[38..40]);
    let source_port = BigEndian::read_u16(&packet[34..36]);
    let dest_port = BigEndian::read_u16(&packet[36..38]);

    let mut header_sum = UDP_PROTO as u32 + source_ip_1 as u32 + source_ip_2 as u32 + dest_ip_1 as u32 + dest_ip_2 as u32 + udp_len as u32 + source_port as u32 + dest_port as u32 + udp_len as u32;
    // println!("Payload Len: {:?}", &payload.len());
    // println!("Payload: {:?}", &payload);
    // println!("First Payload Slice: {:?}", &payload[idx..idx_end]);
    // println!("First BE U32: {:?}", BigEndian::read_u16(&payload[idx..idx_end]) as u32);

    while idx < &payload.len() - 2 {
        header_sum += BigEndian::read_u16(&payload[idx..idx_end]) as u32;
        println!("Header Sum: {:0x?}", &header_sum);
        idx += 2;
        idx_end += 2;
    }

    while header_sum > 0xffff {
        header_sum -= 0xffff;
        header_sum += 1;
    }

    let udp_csum = 0xffff - (header_sum as u16);

    let csum_one: u8 = header_sum as u8;
    let csum_two: u8 = (header_sum >> 8) as u8;
    println!("Calculated CSUM: {:?}", udp_csum);
    println!("Checksum: {:0x}{:0x}", csum_one, csum_two);
    return [csum_one, csum_two];
}```
````

Comment: `payload.to_vec()` creates a new vector. Extending it has no influence on payload.

Comment: udp_len twice since it is in the psuedoheader and actual udp header. https://flylib.com/books/en/3.223.1.122/1/

Comment: payload.to_vec() was so I can push a zero to the end of the payload if it is an odd length so I can still get all of the data as u16.  WIthout .to_vec() it is a [u8] slice and since a slice is immutable it is the best way I could find so far to make that happen.

Comment: I understand the problem with the immutable `packet`, but in this case `payload` has to reference the extended vector, not the original.

Comment: I see what you mean now about needing to actually extend the vector and will make that correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's maybe only a partial solution to the problem.

`payload.to_vec()` creates a new vector.
Extending it has no influence on `payload`.

Making `payload` mutable will enable working on the extended vector if necessary.

Here is a minimal example.

```rust
fn main() {
    let v1 = vec![9, 1, 2, 3];
    let mut v2 = Vec::new(); // empty for now
    let mut sl = &v1[1..]; // could be reassigned to v2
    println!("before v1: {:?}", v1);
    println!("before v2: {:?}", v2);
    println!("before sl: {:?}", sl);
    if sl.len() % 2 != 0 {
        v2 = sl.to_vec();
        v2.push(0);
        sl = &v2[..];
    }
    println!("after v1: {:?}", v1);
    println!("after v2: {:?}", v2);
    println!("after sl: {:?}", sl);
}
/*
before v1: [9, 1, 2, 3]
before v2: []
before sl: [1, 2, 3]
after v1: [9, 1, 2, 3]
after v2: [1, 2, 3, 0]
after sl: [1, 2, 3, 0]
*/
```

Another solution, avoiding the copy, would be to stop one byte earlier (if `payload.len()` is odd) the loop, then deal with the remaining byte.